# Best way to display complex opening hours

Tags: usability

I was wondering if you had any statistics or insight into the best way to display schedules that don't just say: open on a certain day from a certain time to a certain time.

For the moment I have made a table, obviously not really mobile friendly. But on desktop no major problem during user tests.

I wonder, however, if we can do better in a different way

[image]

Most articles on the subject recommend this type of layout. Not convince about that for this context but just need to be convinced

[image: https://medium.com/yext-design/the-anatomy-of-well-designed-business-hours-6d9e2bf54ad0]

and many service companies (banking, insurance, etc.) have this type of presentation. But I can't find any study or figures that would show me that it is better. And no budget to test several versions.

[image]

Do you have any data or comments?

Thanks

Comment: Curious, what kind of data are you looking for?

Comment: Discoverability, average time the user spends to identify information, case studies, return of experience, this kind of thing. I honestly have no idea and have not found anything very conclusive that would allow me to think that a classic table would be better or worse than a bar representation, as I give as an example, to allow the user to identify the information more quickly or more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that most businesses want to make their opening hours (which reflects the customer facing aspects of their operational hours) as simple as possible, as it allows their customers to remember and access their services easily. This would also also them to organise their customer facing services more easily.

My guess is that this is the primary reason why most of the opening hours you see are easily displayed in the format that you see, simply because they are intended to be easy to scan and read.

However, if you find that there are valid reasons for a more complex opening hour setup, then you will probably need to fulfil the purpose of:

- being able to justify the reason for this so that the customers' expectations are set correctly
- being able to provide timely and accurate opening hour information
- being able to display this in the most user friendly way possible

It seems like you have probably done some user testing to know that the third point has been met, and the second point is a technical implementation detail, so I think you'll just have to address the first point.